# getting undefined variable value in reactjs (already import that variable)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load variables conditionally in my demo application.let me explain the problem
I have two files one `delhi.variables.js` and another `lucknow.variables.js`  .Both have same variable names but there values are different .

**delhi.variables.js**

```
export const Name = "delhi";
export const Places = ["ut", "jank"];
```

**lucknow.variables.js**

```
export const Name = "lucknow";
export const Places = ["xd", "pk"];
```

depending on one boolean I need to choose one file in react js . I am trying like this

```
import { isdelhiLocation } from "../utils";

if (isdelhiLocation) {
  require("./delhi.variables");
} else {
  require("./lucknow.variables");
}
```

trying to display value like this

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Name } from "./mock";
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Name);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when I am trying to get this  **console.log(Name);** .I am getting undefined.don't know why

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-dubinsky-3jf35r?file=/src/App.js:0-317

Comment: Shouldn't it be the capital _Name_?

Comment: yup , my bad . but still getting undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't re-export the `variables` from the `./mock/index.js` file. And the variable is `Name`, not `name`.

```js
import { isdelhiLocation } from "../utils";

let variables;
if (isdelhiLocation) {
  variables = require("./delhi.variables");
} else {
  variables = require("./lucknow.variables");
}

module.exports = variables;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-cerf-bxjoly?file=/src/mock/index.js:0-213)